# linker issue or other? dynamically loaded lib

Tags: c, linux, linker

My program loads a dynamic library, but after it tries to load it (it doesn't seem to, or at least something's amiss with the loading. A `free()` throws an error, and I commented out that line.)

I get the following in gdb.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:99
99  ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
    in ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S
```

How would I go about addressing this?

EDIT1:

The above issue was due to me not having an xml file where it should have been.

Here's the first error that I covered up to get to the initial error I showed.

```
(gdb) s
__dlopen (file=0xbfffd03c "/usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so", mode=1)
    at dlopen.c:76
76  dlopen.c: No such file or directory.
    in dlopen.c
(gdb) bt
#0  __dlopen (file=0xbfffd03c "/usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so", 
    mode=1) at dlopen.c:76
#1  0xb7f8680d in visual_plugin_get_references (
    pluginpath=0xbfffd03c "/usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so", 
    count=0xbfffd020) at lv_plugin.c:834
#2  0xb7f86168 in plugin_add_dir_to_list (list=0x804e428, 
    dir=0x804e288 "/usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor") at lv_plugin.c:609
#3  0xb7f86b2b in visual_plugin_get_list (paths=0x804e3d8, 
    ignore_non_existing=1) at lv_plugin.c:943
#4  0xb7f9c5db in visual_init (argc=0xbffff170, argv=0xbffff174)
    at lv_libvisual.c:370
#5  0x080494b7 in main (argc=2, argv=0xbffff204) at client.c:32
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

    Inferior 1 [process 3704] will be killed.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
starlon@lyrical:client$ ls /usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so 
/usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so
starlon@lyrical:client$
```

The file exists. Not sure what's up. Not sure what code to provide either.

Edit2: More info on the file. Permissions are ok.

816K -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 814K 2011-11-08 15:06 /usr/lib/libvisual-0.5/actor/actor_AVS.so

Comment: How about posting some code?  All we can tell is that somewhere, you passed in an invalid pointer to `strlen`.

Comment: It looks like you blew past the end of a string, ie, you do not have a terminating nul.  dlsym and dlopen both require user defined strings.  I would look there first to see if that is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't tell what dynamic library it is.

If it is a free dynamic library -or a library whose source is accessible to you- you can compile it and use it with debugging enabled.

Several Linux distributions -notably Debian & Ubuntu- provide debugging variant of many libraries (e.g. GLibc, GTK, Qt, etc...), so you don't need to rebuild them. For example, Debian has `libgtk-3-0` package (the binary libraries mostly), `libgtk-3-dev` the development files for it (headers, etc...) and `libgtk-3-0-dbg` (the debugging variant of the library). You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH appropriately to use it (since it is in `/usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/libgdk-3.so.0.200.1`).

Sometimes, using the debugging variants of system libraries help you to find bugs in your own code. (Of course, you also need to compile with `-g -Wall` your own code)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was due to a faulty hard drive. Looks like I need a new one.

Comment: Or memory error. This is probable too and may look like hard disk fault.

Comment: I ruled this out by running the same operating system in a VM. The issue still persists. :( It has something to do with Ubuntu.